# PHP - Login form

Tags: php, xampp, netbeans-7

I am new to PHP, I created a login form and home page. I followed the same it is said in the tutorials, but I keep getting the error as 'wrong details' though i provided the right credentials.

// login page

```
    **Login.php**

        <?php
        session_start();
        include_once 'database1.php';

        if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")
        {
         header("Location: index1.php");
        }
        if(isset($_POST['login']))
        {
         $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
         $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
         $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
         $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
         if($row['password']==md5($pass))
         {
          $_SESSION['user'] = $row['number'];
          header("Location: index1.php");
          ?>
        <script> alert ('haii'); </script>
        <?php
         }
         else
         {
          ?>
                <script>alert('wrong details');</script>
                <?php
         }

        }
        ?>
      <html>


    <body>


            <form  method="post" >
         <label><center>EMAIL</center> <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your Email" required /> </label> </br>

         <label>PASSWORD <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Your Password" required /></label> </br>


    <button type="submit" name="login">login</button> </br>
    </br>

    </form>    

    </html>
```

// index page

```
**index1.php**

<?php
session_start();
include_once 'database1.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: login.php");
}
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE number=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>
<html>
<body>
<p> welcome </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using an old tutorial for doing this that is not secure, try something like this http://www.codingcage.com/2015/04/php-login-and-registration-script-with.html

Comment: are you able to share the database contents, as it's a dev environment?

Comment: The line `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` looks like you copied and pasted code from two different sources. It should be `if(isset($_SESSION['user']))`, but I prefer to use `if(!empty($_SESSION['user']))`

Comment: Sidenote: This will give you a false positive `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="")` - The syntax is: "if is set and does not equal to" rather than "if is set not equal to".

Comment: I would suggest to do a little troubleshooting by yourself. In Login.php, do `echo $email; echo $pass;` right below the code, `$pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);` Make sure you are getting the same data you passed from the form. Second thing is do a `print_r($row);` right below the code `$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);` and make sure you are getting the correct data from DB (of course md5 password). Post the results here after these checks.

Comment: Do NOT use `mysql_*` it has been removed and it will not work anymore, use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `mysqli` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @TibinVPaul  **  77@gmail.com77Array ( [0] => 15 [number] => 15 [1] => 77 [id] => 77 [2] => 77 [name] => 77 [3] => 77@gmail.com [email] => 77@gmail.com [4] => 28dd2c7955ce92645624 [password] => 28dd2c7955ce92645624 )

Answer (score 1):

Typically md5 string has 32 characters.

```
echo md5(77); // Result: 28dd2c7955ce926456240b2ff0100bde
```

But in your case, database returns truncated md5 string which has 20 characters.

```
28dd2c7955ce92645624
```

The problem is that your DB password field length is only 20 characters. Please alter your table and set password field length to 32 characters so that it can hold full and correct md5 string.

Comment: That's great. I would be grateful if you mark the answer as correct answer.

Comment: i did that long ago.. but  i joined yesterday itself, so it is asking me to earn a total of 15 reputation to mark it.. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
include_once 'database1.php';
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])!="") {
    header("Location: index1.php");
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['password']==md5($pass)) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $row['number'];
        echo "<script>alert('logged in');</script>"
        header("Location: index1.php");

    }
     else {  
     echo "<script>alert('wrong credentials');</script>"
    } 
}
```